# R: file.path does not output correct subdirectory

Tags: r

I have a directory called "DIR." In this directory are two folders called "programs," which contain R scripts and "data," which contain the .csv files I want to load.

My working directory is set to "C:/User/DIR/programs/processing" and I want to load a file called "flowers.csv" from the "data" folder. ("C:/User/DIR/data/flowers.csv").

I am trying to use the `file.path` function along with the `"../"` to load from the data folder, but it keeps giving me the wrong file path.

```
    dir.root <- setwd("C:/User/DIR/programs/processing")
    dir.in <- file.path(dir.root, "../raw")
```

Gives me

```
    > dir.in
    [1] "\\\\C:/User/DIR/programs/processing/../raw"
```

Instead of what I want `"\\\\C:/User/DIR/raw/"`

When I use

```
    read.csv("../raw/flowers.csv")
```

I get an error that says

```
    Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '../raw/flowers.csv': No such file 
    or directory
```

Can anyone please help me understand what is going on? Thank you!

Comment: Your dir is set to `"C:/User/DIR/programs/processing"` if your data is not in this directory you need to specifically specify where it is. `read.csv("C:/User/DIR/raw/flowers.csv")`

Comment: Hi Chabo, Thanks for your reply. I know I can manually set the path in read.csv. However, my main question is that I thought you could access the directory above ("DIR")  by using "../"  but it seems like that is not the case here. file.path is instead adding the characters "../" to the name of the path, instead of sending me to the DIR folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use normalizePath to convert file path to canonical form.

```
dir.in <- normalizePath(file.path(dir.root, "../raw"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `dir.root` to the wrong path.  `setwd()` doesn't return the path you set, it returns the previous path (so you can return to it later if you want).

Use this code to do what you want:

```
olddir <- setwd("C:/User/DIR/programs/processing")
dir.root <- getwd()
dir.in <- file.path(dir.root, "../raw")
```

You can also call `normalizePath(dir.in)` as @chandra said, but that is not necessary.